# SOQL query on knowledge article

Tags: soql, knowledge

[image]How to create a query that will give me the following information on Draft Knowledge Base Articles: 
Assigned to , Assigned by , Assignment Details (Instructions) ,Assignment Due Date

These fields are there on extreme left panel on snap

**update:**
It seems that this is possible via rest call only. As per me we can not query these fields not atleast via soap. Please prove me wrong and show your efforts by letting me know the object you found.

Comment: Have you tried something or are you unaware which object to query ? It's just that you don't appear to show any own attempt, and this forum is to help, rather than do work for others.

Comment: It really proves the intention. Try your luck and you wont be able to access those fields. It seems that this is possible via rest call only. As per me we can not query these fields not atleast via soap. Please prove me wrong and show your efforts by letting me know the object you found. Kindly avoid my questions in future if you apparently think that those are baseless.

Comment: I did not mean to "attack" you Sara, and what you've just commented clearly already provides more info which would have been a usefull addition to the question.  The difference is that your question didn't show any familiarity with SOQL, while your comment illustrates you've tried and are unable to access these fields.  This transforms the question to asking others to confirm your findings rather than write soql for you. Do you see the difference ?

Comment: I don't see any question mark...

Comment: Hi @SamuelDeRycke I got it, my bad.

Comment: Rest which is partially working is - /services/data/v25.0/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/ID